# Finding an algebraic equation in coins

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Currently I am trying to figure out a pattern in the question:

Charlie, Alison, and Abi want to buy some sweets at the cinema. Sweets cost 32p, and they all have exactly the right amount.
 
Charlie has 3 coins:
20p, 10p, 2p.
Alison has 7 coins:
10p, 5p, 5p, 5p, 5p, 1p, 1p.
Abi has 32 coins. We're not going to list them; we expect you'll be able to work out what she has!
 
Is there a way of making 32p with 4 coins? How about 5 coins?
Or ANY number of coins between 3 and 32?
Explore ways of making other totals using different numbers of coins.

Is it always possible to make a total using every number of coins between the minimum and the maximum?

Any help would be much appreciated!

[IMAGES TO SHOW WHAT I HAVE FOUND ALREADY... PATTERNS IN 2p AND 1p values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPCiS.jpg)

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) may be interesting. In general this problem can be solved algorithmically but is $NP$-hard.

Comment: 10+10+10+2, 10+10+5+5+2, ... Each step you split 10 into 5+5 or 2 into 1+1. If you run out of them, change 5+1 into 2+2+2. So I guess you can do all numbers of coins from 3 to 32.

But can you make 5p with 2 coins or 10p with 3 coins? Some amounts don't work.

Comment: Um  Is it possible to make 32p with 4 coins.  Sure, she has 3 1p coins and one 29p coin... What?  There's no such thing as a 29p coin?  How was I supposed to know that?  Okay, she has 4 8p coins.  What no such thing?  Well, she could have 3 10p and one 2p but there's no such thing as a 2p coin... wait, there is?  Well what coins *are* there? That must be specified to give an answer.

Comment: @Heimdall you can't use 3 coins with value 2p since there is only one.

Comment: "you can't use 3 coins with value 2p since there is only one"  What???  Why do you say that?  Why can't someone have more than one 2p coin?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 20, 10, 5, 2, and 1 value coins.

We can do this by induction:  Suppose you can do it with $n$ coins.

As $20,10 $and $5$ are multiples of $5$ and $32$ has a remainder of $2$ you must either a $2$ or two $1$s.  If you have one $2$ you can replace the $2$ with two $1$s and do it with $n+1$ coins.

If you don't have a $2$ then you have two $1$s.  If you have a $5$ you can replace $5 + 1$ with $2+2+2$ and do it with $n+1$ coins.

If you don't have a $2$ or a $5$ then but you have a $20$ or a $10$ you can replace that with two coins of half value. And do it with $n+1$ coins.

If none of those cases apply then you do not have any $2,5,10,20$.  That means you only have $1$s.  You have $32$ ones.

So if you have $32$ in $n$ coins either you have $32$ coins and can't do it with $33$ or you can do it with $n+1$ coins.

So yes, you can do it for any value of $n=3-32$

Using the above algorithm it is.

$20,10,2$

$20,10,1,1$

$20,5,5,1,1$

$20,5,2,2,2,1$

$20,5,2,2,1,1,1$

$20,5,2,1,1,1,1,1,$

$20,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1$

$20,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1$

$20,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1$

$20,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1$

$20,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1$

$10,10,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1$  etc.

Comment: Thank you! I have added a link to show the patterns I have already found. Is there a way this can be used to work with any total not just 32p?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make any total using any number of coins between the minimum and maximum

For example, £1.51, the smallest number of coins it can be made with is 4 (50, 50, 50, 1)

It is impossible to make this total with 5 coins -

The reason for this is the first two coins have to be 50p

That means you have 3 coins to make 51p

None of those three coins can be 50p or you would have to make the 1p difference with 2 coins which is impossible

That means the largest coin has to be 20p

If two of the remaining 3 coins are 20p then you still need to make 11p with the remaining coin, also impossible

Tl;Dr it's impossible to make £1.51 with 5 coins

Comment: Easier example: 5p can be made with 1 or 5 coins, but not 2 (can do 3 or 4).